# Fixed position navigation bar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, parallax

I'm using an [parallax jquery plugin](https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js)

What parallax.js will do is create a fixed-position element for each parallax image at the start of the document's body. This mirror element will sit behind the other elements and match the position and dimensions of it's target object.

I've added this markup for the navigation:

```
<nav class="nav-inner" role="navigation">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>

</nav>
```

and this CSS :

```
.nav-inner {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:500;
 }
```

The problem is that when I scroll down the navigation doesn't stay fixed on top of the page as I expected.

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vubihatalu/2/) to see it what happens.

Any suggestions on how can I make that navigation bar to stay fixed ?

Comment: What browser are you using? In Firefox it works!

Comment: can you post jsbin code in here that will be use full

Comment: I'm trying it in Chrome, here's full code and example: http://jsbin.com/vubihatalu/2/edit?html,css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `z-index:0` for all your `parallax-mirror` elements

```
.parallax-mirror {z-index:0 !important;}
```

Or change the attribute directly in elements style attribute because it has `z-index:-100`

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. But why does z-index:-100 break the Bootstrap navbar?

Comment: In my experience, z-index:-100 hides the element because it's is placed before all other elements in Z axis, so it's placed before <body>

Answer (score 0):

I usually make my fixed navigation bars differently. Here is my code. It works for me:

CSS:

```
#navBar
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding-left:2em;
    opacity:.9;
    z-index:100;
}

#navBar > a (however you reference your child elements)
{
margin:-4px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="navBar"><a href="">anywhere</a><a href="">anywhere</a></div>
```

If this doesn't work let me know and I'll take a look at my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Since you already use jQuery you can find jQuery plugin like here: http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-fixed-header/